# How to destroy a window?

Tags: xorg, window-manager

Sometimes there's a leftover window in the bottom right area of the screen. It's transparent (invisible), but it will not let me click windows underneath it. I know it's there, after I verified with xwininfo (I can get the id of this window).

So my question is: how can I destroy this window (so that I won't have to restart/logout to get rid of it)?

More details: there was a command to get the owner process of a window but I can't remember it right now. However, I did try it, and couldn't retrieve a process. Likely, the window is orphaned. So I just need an X specific way to destroy the window as the owner process likely no longer exists.

Comment: If this happens with Ubuntu 11.04 in a Unity or a classic session with Compiz/effects, you might be interested in following [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/709461).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `xkill`? Run that from a terminal or a run window, click the window and it *should* nuke it.

If it's a common issue, it might be worth making a desktop launcher so you can run `xkill` with a double-click. You can do that the normal way or just throw this into a terminal:

```
echo "[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
Exec=xkill
Name=xkill" > ~/Desktop/xkill.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm not sure who created this window. Could have been something low-level like Unity or Compiz because after killing it the screen flashed a bit like some such low level component was reloading. Anyway, the system continued to work great afterwards.

Comment: I believe it may be killing X or Compiz or Unity because the window is somehow orphaned. Will still look, maybe there's a way to destroy just the window and not the owner process. Feel free to write here if you have comments about what I just wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Run `xkill` and select the window.